# MySQL. Select and split GROUP_CONCAT into different columns

Tags: mysql

I'm noob in MySQL...
It is difficult to describe my task, so I will show it with an example.

I have two tables:

1. `meta_data`:

[image]

```
id  key value
1   property_1  1,2,54,2
1   property_2  23424
1   property_3  cat
1   property_4  4324
1   property_5  3231
1   property_6  45
1   property_7  423424
1   property_8  868
1   property_9  2424
1   property_10 886
1   property_11 535
1   property_12 3434
1   property_13 686
1   property_14 55
1   property_15 23424
1   property_16 54534
1   property_17 868
1   property_18 4556
1   property_19 5345
1   property_20 43535
2   property_1  54,92,22
2   property_2  43443
2   property_3  dog
2   property_4  343
2   property_5  2342
2   property_6  34
```

2. `users`:

[image]

```
id  email
1   sdfs@ya.ru
2   gdgd@ya.ru
3   ffdg@ya.ru
4   fgdfgdf@ya.ru
5   gfg@ya.ru
6   dffet@ya.ru
7   gfg@ya.ru
8   gfg@ya.ru
9   hjg@ya.ru
```

And after call the stored procedure I want to get this:

[image]

```
id  property_1  property_2  property_3  email
1   "1,2,54,2"  "23424"     "cat"       "sdfs@ya.ru"
```

The procedure must get an input `parameter` (for example "cat") and:

1. find the line where `property_3` is equal to the input `parameter` and get the id from this row (for example "1"),
2. select the fields, that I need, from the `meta_data` table, where the `id` is equal to our `id` from the first point (for example `property_1`, `property_2`, `property_3`),
3. then rotate them from rows to columns,
4. and finally add `email` from `user` table with the same `id`.

All this if a `property_3` match was found.

---

I think I can do it with lots of SELECT/FROM, but it seems too complicated to me.

I tried to use `CASE WHEN ___ LIKE ___ THEN ___ END` but I couldn't succeed. In this case I get cells with null after grouping:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN meta_data.key LIKE 'property_1' THEN meta_data.value END AS property_1,
       CASE WHEN meta_data.key LIKE 'property_2' THEN meta_data.value END AS property_2,
       CASE WHEN meta_data.key LIKE 'property_3' THEN meta_data.value END AS property_3
FROM meta_data
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your simple data as text not images, so it can be easy to help you

Comment: yes, of course. sorry

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure for this?

Comment: And what should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   meta_data1.value AS property_1,
   meta_data2.value AS property_2,
   meta_data3.value AS property_3,
   email
FROM 
   meta_data AS meta_data1, 
   meta_data AS meta_data2, 
   meta_data AS meta_data3,
   users
WHERE
   meta_data1.id = users.id AND
   meta_data2.id = users.id AND
   meta_data3.id = users.id AND
   meta_data1.key = "property_1" AND
   meta_data2.key = "property_2" AND
   meta_data3.key = "property_3"
```

Comment: Fantastic! I added `... AND meta_data3.value = @parametrt` and it works great! Thanks

Comment: Note, that it would break if one of the property is missing. In such a case, you should use a LEFT JOIN or something like this to make the user printed with a NULL property.

Answer (score 0):

This an optimized way to do it using `GROUP BY` with the aggregate function `MAX()`:

```
SELECT m.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.key_ LIKE 'property_1' THEN m.value_ END) AS property_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.key_ LIKE 'property_2' THEN m.value_ END) AS property_2,
       max(CASE WHEN m.key_ LIKE 'property_3' THEN m.value_ END) AS property_3,
       MAX(u.email)
FROM meta_data m
inner join users u on u.id = m.id
group by m.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T2cuhfTw)

Comment: I had to wrap SELECT around FROM to add WHERE. https://dbfiddle.uk/xDsrwIff
The solution proposed by Frédéric runs on average 30 times faster. This is strange, at first it seemed to me that your solution would be faster.